# How do i get the list of ids of feetype followed by student id

Tags: types, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to show data of students against class and section, all thing is done but I'm stuck in to show the list fees against their fee type Ids followed by student id according to class and section in my controller.

`Class:VIII Section:Blue
|StudentName|Class|Section|GrandTotal|Admission Fee|TutionFee|TransportFee|
|Ali        |VIII |Blue   | 20$      |   5$        |     11$ |    4$      |
|Jastin     |VIII |Blue   | 20$      |   5$        |     11$ |    4$      |
|Kim        |VIII |Blue   | 20$      |   5$        |     11$ |    4$      |`

```
     `public JsonResult StudentSearch(int? classId,int?sectionId)
      {
        var listOfIds = _dbContext.STUDENT_FEE_DETAIL
        .Where(n=>n.STUDENT_FEE_ID ==n.StudentFee.STUDENT_FEE_ID)
        .Select(n=>n.AMOUNT);
        var fee = _dbContext.STUDENT_FEE.ToList().Where(c=>c.IsActive);
        var sec = _dbContext.SECTION.ToList();
        List<StudentInfoViewModel> SiVM =new List<StudentInfoViewModel>();
        if (classId >0 && sectionId>0)
            {
               var students = _dbContext.STUDENTINFO.Include(i =>i.Class).
               ThenInclude(c => c.Section).Where(c=>c.ClassId== classId 
                        && c.SectionId == sectionId);
               foreach (var item in students)
         {
              SiVM.Add(new StudentInfoViewModel
                { Id = item.Id,
                    AdmissionNumber = item.AdmissionNumber,
                    FullName = item.FullName,
                    ClassName = item.Class.ClassName,
                    SectionName = sec.Where(c => c.Id == sectionId)
                .Select(c => c.SectionName).FirstOrDefault(),
                    AmountDue = fee.Where(c => c.STUDENT_INFO_ID == 
                  item.Id && c.STUDENT_INFO.IsActive)
                   .Select(e =>e.GRAND_TOTAL).FirstOrDefault(),
                    StdFeeTypeDetail =listOfIds.ToString().FirstOrDefault(),
               });
            }
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(false);
            }
        return Json(SiVM);
    }`
```

`StdFeeTypeDetail` is a `float`in `StudentInfoViewModel`..
plz help me Im new in Asp.net core

Comment: Share us what you have, and what result you expected? It is difficult to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I get the list of fees against its student id in `listOfIds`

`var listOfIds = _dbContext.STUDENT_FEE_DETAIL
                           .Where(n=>n.STUDENT_FEE_ID==n.StudentFee.STUDENT_FEE_ID)
                          .Select(n=> new {
                                           feeid = n.FEE_TYPE_ID,
                                           feetypeName= n.FEE_TYPE.Name,
                                           amount= n.AMOUNT,
                                           studentid= n.StudentFee.STUDENT_INFO_ID,
                                           studentName=n.StudentFee.STUDENT_INFO.FullName
                                           }).GroupBy(x => x.studentid).ToList();`

But i get problem  it in foreach loop
[image]

Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IGrouping(int,float?) to 'float'